# AngularJS ng-checked rendering issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of user-details stored in `userList`.
I am rendering these list of users in a div tag as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li class="extra-users" ng-repeat="member in view.userList">
    <input class="add-friends-check add-friends{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-checked="member.ischeck" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now Problem occurs If same userList is used to render users in multiple div tags.
i.e.

```
<div class="1">
<ul>
  <li class="extra-users" ng-repeat="member in view.userList">
    <input class="add-friends-check add-friends{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-checked="member.ischeck" />
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="2">
<ul>
  <li class="extra-users" ng-repeat="member in view.userList">
    <input class="add-friends-check add-friends{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-checked="member.ischeck" />
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now If two users are selected/checked in div1, it gets reflected in div2 as well since view.userList is getting updated.

One way to solve it is clone userList and assign cloned userList` to div1 and userList`` to div2.
But that is causing me performance issues If I load more than 15 or 20 divs.

Is there any way we can avoid selecting a user in one div not reflecting in another?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you sure member.ischeck is working correctly? Add jsfiddle to play with.

Comment: It is doable with two different `$scope` objects. Something like [**this**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Zko0jTiT2Py5Fal7C2A?p=preview). However, can you please explain why you want to render the same list twice?

Comment: I am implementing a chat application where user can click on a contact to start chat. On click of each contact, a small window opens for chat.So user can open multiple windows and chat with multiple people simultaneously. Each window has add people option which shows list of users: This list  is nothing but userList what I mentioned above

Comment: @Abhishek IMO, you may need to write [**angularjs directive with isolated scope**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and use it for chat windows. An example of Angular modalDialog [**here**](http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/)